# SQL Server 2005 - Returning 0 when counting

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Assuming that I have 3 tables

```
Status
ID  Value
1 - Active
2 - Inactive
3 - Pending

Users
ID  Value
1 - John
2 - Bryan

UserStatus
ID_Status   ID_USER
1              1
2              3
```

I want to return how many users I have per status, but in this case there are 0 users on Inactive and I do need to return those in the result set, so, for this case it should return Active (1) - Pending (1) and Inactive(0)
What is the best way to archieve this?

Comment: you could have posted your query here. anyway, next time then.

Comment: Yes i should! Actually the answer was real simple, guess i couldnt think after work for over 30 hours without sleep. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `left join`:

```
select s.value, count(us.id_status)
from status s left join
     userstatus us
     on s.id = us.id_status
group by s.value;
```